# How to use generic types on various abstract methods

Tags: java, generic-type-argument

I'm currently developing a Java class that uses another class, having this last some generic Types.

So, the class using generic types is this one

```
public abstract class DataStream <T, S, V>{
    protected T   input;
    protected S   output;
    protected int index;

    public DataStream(T input){
        this.input = input;
        this.index = 0;
        this.run();
    }

    public DataStream(T input, boolean run){
        this.input = input;
        this.index = 0;

        if(run)
            this.run();
    }

    protected abstract void run();
    protected abstract V get();
}
```

then, the class that uses it looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass{
    protected abstract DataStream method1(DataStream aStream);
    protected abstract DataStream method2(DataStream bStream, DataStream pattern);
    protected abstract DataStream method3(DataStream hStream, DataStream rStream);
}
```

So, `method1`, `method2`, and `method3` could be implemented on classes extending MyClass, but I'm not sure is totally OK to let the methods like this, or is **needed** to specify  on each signature (as I'm having some warnings, I'm not sure).

Will this implementation works? Do I need to specify everytime the values of ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Those warnings (which I assume are “raw type” warnings) matter.  Do not ignore them.  You need to specify generic arguments after every occurrence of `DataStream` in your code.  If you truly don’t care about the actual generic types, you can use `?` for each argument.

Comment: Ok, thanks @VGR. I do not tend to ignore warnings... that's why I asked (I never used gen. types before). So, basically, if let's say you, want to implement `MyClassExtended`, and on that implementation you specify <T, S, V> (for example `protected final DataStream<int, int, int>`), this can be a problem with my actual implementation, right? So if I add <?, ?, ?> on my methods can work? Thank you.

Comment: Whether it’s a problem depends on your design and what you do with the DataStreams.  You probably want to place the generic types on your own class:  `public abstract class MyClass<T, S, V>`  Then you can write `DataStream<T, S, V>` in your class, and authors of subclasses can have full type safety with their own DataStreams.

Comment: But the problem is that problably some author wants to do `protected DataStream<int, int, int> method1(DataStream<int, int, int> a)`, and then `protected DataStream<float, int, String> method2...` So if I force to specify <T, S, V> on `MyClass` then it will be impossible to do such thing. On this point I think the best way is to use, as you said, <?, ?, ?>, rigth?

Comment: Then you’ll need more than three generic types.  Something like `public abstract class MyClass<T1, S1, V1, T2, S2, V2, T3, S3, V3>`.  Obviously, this is unwieldy, and should make you rethink your design.  “Forced subclassing” is usually an antipattern anyway.  That’s why Java stopped doing it in the 90s, when they changed AWT components to use listeners.